# What dimensions to choose when winding your own inductor

Tags: impedance, filter, inductor

Suppose you want to make a [wilkinson 3-way splitter with lumped components](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/6201/how-can-a-quarter-wave-transmission-line-transformer-be-implemented-with-lumped)

Given the following circuit, you need a 31.5nH inductor

[image]

The inductor can be wound various ways:

1. 3 wdg, 1 cm diameter, 2.36 cm long
2. 2 wdg, 1 cm diameter, 0.8 cm long
3. 3 wdg, 0.5 cm diameter, 0.48 cm long

These are examples, you can calculate more variations for this.

My question is, given the example of building a wilkinson 3-way splitter with lumped components as described in the link above, for 435 MHz from the same example, for 50 Watts transmit power: **what way should the inductor be constructed ?**

thanks

Comment: [How does one read a ferrite datasheet?](http://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/1159/how-does-one-read-a-ferrite-datasheet)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It boils down to practical issues — you want to make it as small as possible, but no smaller.

The power-handling requirements will dictate the wire diameter (to handle the current) and the end-to-end spacing (to handle the voltage). For an air-core coil, you also want the wire to be stiff enough to hold its shape well.

You will want to wind the coil on some sort of handy form (drill bits are useful for this), so this puts some limits on your choice of inside diameter. The one variable you have the most flexibility with is the length. Indeed, it is possible to tweak the final inductance value after construction by squeezing/stretching the length of the coil a bit.

Comment: +1. Also if there are two or three air-core inductors it's good to lay them out with orthogonal axes to minimize mutual inductance.